# How to validate a textbox to check if the value entered is in multiples of 100 only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to validate that the value entered by a user in a textbox is a multiple of 100 using jQuery. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of fun ways. Lets collect the input value itself:

```
var input = $('#textbox').val();
```

So, ways:

1. The boring right way

   ```
   if (parseInt(input,10) % 100 === 0)
   ```
2. A bit more fun way

   ```
   if (input.substr(-2)==='00')
   ```
3. "I love odd bases"

   ```
   if (parseInt(value,13) % parseInt('79',13) === 0)
   ```
4. Regexes

   ```
   if (input.match(/[1-9]+00$/))
   ```
5. More fun (but definitely more robust) regexes

   ```
   if (input.match(/\s*\d+0{2}\s*$/))
   ```
6. And the winner is...

   ```
   if ((input.search(/\s*\d+0{2}\s*$/)==-1?"false":"true" !== "false"))
   ```

But if I were you I'd stop with first way. :)

Answer (score 6):

This will check whether the value of the element matching `#example` is a multiple of 100 and store the result (`true` or `false`) in `multiple`:

```
$("#example").change(function() {
   var multiple = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) % 100 == 0; 
});
```

Note that this will result in `0` returning `true`, so you may want to add a check in for that.

Here's a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/EvZSA/). See [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_%28Modulus%29) for more information on the modulus operator.

**Update** (based on comments)

As noted by @PaulPRO in the comments, the above will also return true for numbers such as 100.973. If you want to deal with floating point numbers as well as integers, simply use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`. Here's another [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/EvZSA/2/), and here's some updated code:

```
$("#example").change(function() {
   var multiple = parseFloat($(this).val()) % 100 == 0; 
});
```

Comment: Not sure if it matters to the OP, but 100.973 will also be considered valid with this.

Comment: @PaulPRO - Good point. I've updated the answer with an alternative to deal with that.

Comment: cool :) +1 This will also accept a string like `"100 dollars"` as valid, but perhaps the OP desires that.

Comment: Hmm. Another good point! +1 to your answer for a stricter alternative!

Answer (score 2):

```
if (parseInt($("#yourtextbox").val()) % 100 === 0) {
    // is multiple of 100
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to check if the remainder is 0.

http://jsfiddle.net/jSfXC/

Comment: I'm not sure why this got down-voted - I would have thought just the word "modulo" would have been enough for the asker to figure it out.

Comment: Indeed, I even supplied a JS example.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work for you:

```
var input = document.getElementById('mult-100');
if(input.value.match(/^[1-9]\d*00$/))
    return false;
// Not a multiple of 100
alert('Please enter a multiple of 100');
```

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/rtzeQ/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(value % 100 == 0) { // if the remainder of a division by 100 is 0
  // divides by 100
} else {
  // doesn't!
}
```

As poweroy says this is a Modulo (see his link). Its just the percentage sign. What it does is returns the remainder of a division.

### EG

```
5/2 == 2 remainder 1
5 % 2 == 1 (the remainder)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( parseInt($('#input').val(), 10) % 100 !== 0 ) {
   alert('Value isn't a multiple of 100');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#your_input_selector').keyup(function(){ alert('100 multiple? ' $(this).val() % 100 == 0)});
```